# How to count the sum value of sub and main categories in two different tables (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a mysql jdbc query statment,to make a report for a certain day.

I have 2 tables,

1st 
null represents, it's a main category, if maincategory is not null,then it's a sub category, that way I can make unlimited node depth

```
id|name      |maincategoryname
1 |watch tv  |free-time
2 |videogames|free-time
3 |play vg   |videogames
4 |free-time |null
5 |commuting |null
6 |working   |null
7 |jogging   |free-time
8 |winning vg|play vg
```

2nd table

```
id|name       |start|end  |duration|opinion    |date
1 |commuting  |00:30|01:00|0:30    |boring     |2017.02.08.    
2 |playing vg |01:10|02:10|1:00    |boring     |2017.02.08.
3 |free-time  |03:00|04:00|1:00    |slow       |2017.02.08.
4 |free-time  |05:00|07:00|2:00    |interesting|2017.02.08.
5 |playing vg |09:00|09:30|0:30    |interesting|2017.02.08.
6 |commuting  |10:00|13:00|3:00    |-          |2017.02.08.
7 |jogging    |13:00|15:30|2:30    |interesting|2017.02.08.
8 |winning vg |15:30|15:40|0:10    |good       |2017.02.08.    
9 |commuting  |10:00|13:00|3:00    |-          |2017.02.10.
```

Present maincategory should be separated by their child, sub categories, if no sub category is presten, for a subcategory, then it's listed after the main category.
Each parent category should also contain their child's summarized duration, and opinion

I really grinded my gear on that one, but cant come up with a working solution

I was working on a solution:

1, get the union of the 2 tables

2, get the summarized value of each time period for each name
thats where I stuck, and ended up failing

3, 1 by 1 check if any above is a main category of the activity and sum their total time, and opinion

> update 1

the correct output should be:
prodouct after searching 2017.02.08:

```
name      |total|opinion
commuting |3:30 |boring , -
free-time |7:10 |boring,slow,interesting,interesting,good
playing vg|1:40 |boring,interesting,good
winning vg|0:10 |good
jogging   |2:30 |interesting
```

Comment: can you please provide some more info on the required output and if possible can you create sql fiddle with sample data

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kSxbam2w (fixed link)

Comment: i got the schema , can you explain your expected output

Comment: also messed up a 1 with a ! http://pastebin.com/nnVXdq5f

Comment: so the first table holds the child and parent table for each activity.
the second table is made of a scedule. Separated by dates, I date (expl: 2017.02.08. is the date i'm looking for, this is the biggest pile.
I want to display a categorized sum of all the activities of the selected day. the time periods and the comments should be summed up to each activity

for each category level should be displayed a summarized time example if a category has a subcategory, then the sum of the periods of each child should be displayed next to it, and also opinions

Comment: check this query 
select tMain.name,SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `duration` ) ) ),group_concat(opinion) from (select name from (select name from table1 where maincategoryname is null) as t
union
select t2.name from table1 t1 join table1 t2 on t1.name = t2.maincategoryname) as tMain join table2 t2 on tMain.name =t2.name
where date='2017.02.08.' group by name

Comment: Chintan Udeshi, thank you so much. You helped a lot.
Your query is pretty complex(atleast for me), yet I'm still learning

Comment: it gave correct result then i can post that as answer

Comment: Just realised that I've mistyped 
"INSERT INTO mydb.table1 (id, name, maincategoryname) VALUES ('3', 'playvg', 'videogames');" 'playvg' instead of 'playingvg'.

Dont want to sound picky, but it's not a completel solution. (i know it sounds stupid)each upper category should inherit their lower level category's 'opinion' and 'duraiton as well'
just like on the 3rd code, 
playingvg should inherit 0:10 from wining vg turning it to 1:40, and freetime should inheritthat 1:40 from playingvg making it 4:40. Same with opinions

Comment: reread my answer, I wasnt that clear about that

Comment: ok if that is the case then jogging - 02:30 also should be added to free-time as it is also child of free-time

Comment: yes, exactly, sorry for missing that one out, I was a bit exhausted

Comment: so can you please share the expected output so i can complete the query

Comment: updated main topic